# How to manage empty's get param on nodes router?

Tags: node.js, express, get, httprequest, angular13

I do request from an Angular (13) app to a NodeJs server, this way:

```
getJobData(selectedCandle, bypassLoader = false) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.endpoint}/getJobData/${selectedCandle}`, { context: bypassLoaderContext(bypassLoader) });
}
```

And I intercept them on NodeJs with Express:

```
router.get('/getJobData/:selectedCandle(.{0,})', helpers.restAuthorize, async (req, res) => {
}
```

Problem is: if `selectedCandle` is empty, it doesn't found the route. It only works when `selectedCandle` is not "". How can I deal both situation? - i.e. simply pass empty if its empty or value if its valued?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a question mark at the end of the parameter to make it optional i.e.

```
router.get('/getJobData/:selectedCandle(.{0,})?', helpers.restAuthorize, async (req, res) => {
}
```